# Want to remove Spinning wheel icon which shows while website loads

Tags: jquery, html, css

When the website [trueconf.in](http://trueconf.in) starts loading you will start seeing the contents but then it will show a blue spinning wheel icon which hides all the contents making the background white.

Can someone please help me on how I could remove that spinning wheel icon with white background. I mean i don't need this icon etc i just want to the user to see the content loading live instead of this spinning wheel icon.

Comment: By opening the link I dont find any spinning wheel. And yes that's called loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this css

```
.loader, .loader_inner
{ display: none;}
```

Comment: this is the code which displays preloader. Try to hide this with my css <div class="loader">
        <div class="loader_inner"></div>
</div>

Comment: my website is too damn slow....does combining the JS and CSS files in one files will help??????

Comment: No, it won't. Try to minify your css and js files. It will help a little.

Comment: Thanks.....in pingdom tools etc it shows that all of my javascripts are render blocking how can i get over this issue???